# Scientific Notation is badly written to csv from python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, export-to-csv

I'm totally puzzled by the situation at hand. I have a large dataset with a broad range of numbers, all between 0 and 2. However, when I write the data to a .csv file with

```
df_Signals.to_csv('signals_IDG_TOut1.csv', sep=',')
```

to be able to import the file in another program something strange happens. When I for example call the number with

```
print(df_Signals["Column"].iloc[44])
```

python prints: 2.8147020866287068e-05

However, when I open the .csv file it reads 281470208662,87. A quick inspection shows that this happens for all number written in E-notation I could find. I have tried to figure out what is going on, but have no idea what the answer is . So my main question is: Why? And secondly, how can I resolve this? And is this a structural problem when exporting to .csv files?

I use PyCharm 2017.1.4, with the Anaconda 3 interpreter.

Regards

Update: As the comments correctly pointed out, it is Excel that wrongly opens the data. Which still intrigues me why that happens.

Comment: We're going to need to see a [mcve] for that.

Comment: What are you opening the CSV file with?

Comment: View the .csv with text editor! Make sure that your default .csv program (like Excel) is not mangling your text.

Comment: You are totally right, it is Excel who wrongly translates the data. Now I still wonder how this happens, but it has as least solved part of the problem. Should have been the first thing to do, open it with text editor, thanks